# C++ inheritance how to get variables values

Tags: c++, variables, inheritance

I'm trying to create a small program for a lessons.
But In My class that herit , I don't have values of the superclass.
, here's the  code

Point.h

```
#ifndef Point_H
#define Point_H
#include <iostream>
class Point{
  public:
         Point();
         void set_values (int a, int b);
         void set_values (int a, int b, int c);
         void affichervaleurs();
  protected:
         int x ;
         int y ;
         int z ;
  };
#endif
```

Point.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"

using namespace std;

Point::Point(){
         x=0;
         y=0;
         z=0;
  };     
void Point::set_values (int a, int b){
 x=a;
 y=b;
}
void Point::set_values (int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0){
 x=a;
 y=b;
 z=c;
}
void Point::affichervaleurs(){
 cout << "X = " << x << endl;
 cout << "Y = " << y << endl;
}
```

Carre.h

```
#ifndef Carre_H
#define Carre_H
#include "Point.h"

class Carre:public Point{      
  public:
         int Aire (){
         };
         void affichercar(){
         };

  };
#endif
```

Carre.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Point.h"

class Carre:public Point{
  public:
         //Carre::Carre(int a, int b);
         int Aire (){
             return (x * y); 
         }
         void affichercar(){
             cout << "Coordonnees X:" << x  << endl;
         }

  };
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Carre.h"
#include "Point.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
Point MonPoint ;
cout << "Default values:"  << endl;
MonPoint.affichervaleurs();

MonPoint.set_values(4,6);
cout << "Setting values:"  << endl;
MonPoint.affichervaleurs();

Carre MonCarre;
MonCarre.set_values(4,6,0);

MonCarre.set_values(5,8);
MonCarre.affichercar();
cout << MonCarre.Aire()  << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is, when I call this line :

```
cout << MonCarre.Aire()  << endl;
```

it returns a strange number. I'm sure that the problem is here :

```
         int Aire (){
              return (x * y); 
         };
```

Like the x and y are not linked with the superclass.

Can someone help me how to access my x and y values from my superclass in my class Carre ?

Other strange thing this line doesn't appear :

```
MonCarre.affichercar();
```

Thanks

Comment: Your `point.h` code is wrong; you've pasted the class definition for `Carre`. Please update your question.

Comment: I'm still confused; your Carre.cpp includes the *redefinition* of your class.

Comment: Looks like OP want to do a code review -- should it be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Your `Point::set_values(int, int, int)` has no default arguments in its declaration, only in its definition. This is very strange. If you want the member function to take default arguments, specify them in the declaration, and do not repeat them in the function definition. That said, which one of the two `set_values` overloads do you expect to be called for `MonCarre.set_values(5,8);`? I'm asking because the calls to `set_values` in `main` with two arguments are ambiguous, and your code probably does not even compile.

Comment: I think there are some design issues. First, it is generally a bad idea to have protected data members. This defined a strong coupling because child classes depend on implementation internals of your base class. Second, I think it is fundamentally wrong to say "A Carre (rectangle?) is a point", but this is what the inheritance models. Wouldn't it make more sense for a Carre to have two point members?

Comment: It's not for a code review, it's becuase it's doesn't work. Why In my Carre.cpp I can't access the 'x' value that is inside the Point.h I herit , I'm new with heritage, so How I can get the x value in my Carre class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the functions `Aire` and `affichercar` in Carre.h, but you need to declare them only if you want to write an implementation in Carre.cpp.

Edit: and your Carre.cpp is also wrong. You just need to rewrite Carre.* files.

Edit2. Let me do some code review and give you a working version of your code - just summarizing what was discussed in comments and my own thoughts.

Point.h

```
void set_values (int a, int b);
void set_values (int a, int b, int c);
```

If you want to define the default values of the arguments of the second function, you should do it in its declaration as was suggested in comments to your question. So it will be

```
void set_values (int a, int b);
void set_values (int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0);
```

But in this case it's not clear what function should be called if you write, for example, `set_values(1, 2)`, therefore your code won't compile because of ambiguity (as also was mentioned in the comments). So you just have to keep only one extended version of this function with the default arguments. The Point.h will be in this case:

```
#ifndef Point_H
#define Point_H
#include <iostream>
class Point{
  public:
         Point();
         void set_values (int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0);
         void affichervaleurs();
  protected:
         int x ;
         int y ;
         int z ;
  };
#endif
```

The Point.cpp is also changed a little bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
using namespace std;
Point::Point()
 // it's better to initialize these variables here
 // : x(0), y(0), z(0)
{
  x=0;
  y=0;
  z=0;
}
void Point::set_values (int a, int b, int c){
 x=a;
 y=b;
 z=c;
}
void Point::affichervaleurs(){
 cout << "X = " << x << endl;
 cout << "Y = " << y << endl;
}
```

Now let's consider the Carre.h file

```
class Carre:public Point{      
  public:
    // IT'S DEFINITION WHICH IS USED WHEN YOU CALL THE FUNCTION
    int Aire (){};
    // IT'S DEFINITION WHICH IS USED WHEN YOU CALL THE FUNCTION
    void affichercar(){};    
  };
```

Now I'm starting answering your questions:

> The problem is, when I call this line :
>   cout << MonCarre.Aire()  << endl;
>   it returns a strange number.

Yes, it's a strange number returned by the function *defined* in the Carre.h (not Carre.cpp) file.

> I'm sure that the problem is here :
>           int Aire (){
>                return (x * y); 
>           };

No, as you see, it's not.

> Like the x and y are not linked with the superclass.

In fact they are.

> Can someone help me how to access my x and y values from my superclass in my class Carre ?

You already have this access. It's okay to use protected members from base class in derived class in case of public inheritance.

> Other strange thing this line doesn't appear : MonCarre.affichercar();

You mean it does nothing? But it's in perfect consistency with how you implement (*define*) the function in Carre.h (not Carre.cpp) file.

So let me change the code to make it work.

Carre.h

```
#ifndef Carre_H
#define Carre_H
#include "Point.h"

class Carre:public Point{      
  public:
         int Aire (); // now it's declaration
         void affichercar(); // now it's declaration

  };
#endif
```

Carre.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Carre::Aire (){
  return (x * y); 
}
void Carre::affichercar(){
  cout << "Coordonnees X:" << x  << endl;
}
```

I didn't compile this for myself, but the whole idea should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

> > access my x and y values

From within `Carre`, you simply access them by 'x' and 'y'.

From outside, you cannot as they are not public.

Comment: I think that's what I'm doing it ? in my class : Carre I'm doing this :   int Aire (){
              return (x * y); 
         }; but the return value, is not 5 * 8.... I don't know if I forget something, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sure, if you don't get compilation errors then you are probably doing it right -- if the output is not as expected you may need to debug the program, but I didn't think that was your question (i.e. "help me debug the program...")

Comment: The thing is , that the return value from Carre.Aire doesn't return x*y, like if the value we're not good. That's why I ask if I forget something, or maybe someone see a mistake in the code.

Comment: (1) This site is not for code reviews. (2) I don't know what output you are seeing, or why you believe that is not correct output. (3) Try to run your code in a debugger and singlestep though the code.